# Override Authorizable can method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've recently inherited this quite new Laravel project (it was 8, I've since upgraded to 9), and they use `$request->user()?->can('some_permission')` a lot of places. But they also have a `user_level` property on the user that is either 100 for admin or 0 for normal user (don't ask why they've set it as a number, I have no clue). So the admin users don't get any permissions set, which means that they of course get `false` for any `can()` check. Is there a way to override the `can()` method to return true if `user_level` is set to 100? Or is there another way to have admin users always get all available permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of a Policy's [before()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#policy-filters) method. If you want to check something, `before` is run first (if it is present in the Policy) and if it returns `true`, it will automatically allow.

---

In your example, I think it should be:

```php
public function before(User $user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->user_level >= 100) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that would work if I had permission check defined in policies. But right now there's a bunch of `$request->user()?->can('some_permission')` checks all over the place, and the `before()` method doesn't seem to work for those. I guess it would be cleaner to move the checks over to policies anyway, so looks like I'll just have to roll up my sleeves and get cracking!

Comment: Oh yeah, if I am not confused (I can't correctly remember), you can define `gates`, and they would still be accessible using `can`, so having `can` method being used does not mean you have a `Policy`, so yeah